# How can i add a logo (and a border) to an image?

Tags: javascript, image, cordova

i am writing a project where the user will select an image, than select a border and a logo. The border and the logo both will also be selected by the user.

I need to generate a new image (JPEG or PNG) based on these 3 images, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuziN.jpg) is an example of how an output should look. I couldn't find any libraries that could help me, all i found was how to crop and rotate images, but nothing on how to add an image over another.

Tnis project is using phonegap, so ideally, the solution should use Javascript.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use canvas to get Image and Draw it according to your needs.

Comment: yeah, that ended being the simplest solution.I am using [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/))